# Ask user to insert values in array

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

I am trying to do a for loop, in a way that users can insert data into an array.
Everytime I run the code, the first input field lets me insert 2 values instead of just one, whereas the rest of the 11 fields, only let me input one.
Can you guys tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Here's the code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int count = 12;
    int months[count];
    int option, choice;

    printf("Insert the value of each month:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("%dº month: \n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d\n", &months[i]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

The result code is this:

```
Introduza o valor produzido em cada mês:
1º month: 
1
2
2º month: 
3
3º month: 
4
4º month: 
5
5º month: 
6
6º month: 
7
7º month: 
8
8º month: 
9
9º month: 
0
10º month: 
1
11º month: 
2
12º month: 
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\n` character in your `scanf` format string will cause `scanf` to only return once all subsequent whitespace characters have been consumed and a non-whitespace character is encountered. This is probably not what you want.

Removing this character will probably cause your program to behave as intended.

Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. However, this is not the reason for your problem. See this page for further information about why it is important to check the return value of `scanf`: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! It was indeed the problem in my code.